# Flask app.py stopped working in pycharm

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask and pycharm. Basically I wrote a rest webservice and initially PyCharm was running it as a python script. Everything was working fine. But then after I realuched pycharm it detects app.py as a flask application.

Part that launches the app locally in app.py looks like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from db import db

    db.init_app(app)

    if app.config['DEBUG']:
        @app.before_first_request
        def create_tables():
            db.create_all()

    app.run(port=5000)
```

The problem is that it seems like this part is not executed when I try to run app.py. I also have `run.py` which I use to run the app through uwsgi on a web server.
Here is the console output from *pycharm* when I launch `app.py`:

```
FLASK_APP = app.py
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 0
In folder /home/username/PycharmProjects/psychotest
/home/aydar/PycharmProjects/psychotest/venv/bin/python -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I've added print statements to the `if __name__=='main'` block, which are never printed. It also seems that pycharm launches flask with `/home/username/PycharmProjects/psychotest/venv/bin/python -m flask run`. Also as you can see `DEBUG` is false, even though I explicitly set debug to true in the body of app.py like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

Everything is working through the terminal with just `python app.py`. How do I change this behaviour of Pycharm? It annoys me because I get sqlalchemy errors every time I try to get something from a database through flask. Error example:

```
    'The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current ' \
AssertionError: The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current application.  Please make sure to call init_app() first.
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764073/sqlalchemy-extension-isnt-registered-when-running-app-with-gunicorn) answer, because PyCharm is detecting it as a flask app, the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block is never being hit, so you probably want to move your `db.init_app(app)` outside that block (the import too)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to solve the problem. While reformating `app.py`, namely moving `db.init_app()` outside of `__name__=='__main__'`, works - it was not ideal solution for me. Because I've already set up workflow, and I did not want to change execution logic of app.py just for PyCharm.

The solution was to disable flask integration in settings -> languages and frameworks. Everything works properly now.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit your configuration runned by Pycharm.

You can find it on the top right. There is a select box which your current configuration is selected.

Then don't use `-m flask run` as parameter but just `app.py`.

Comment: can't find it. Can you post as screenshot maybe? Here is how my pycharm looks like: https://imgur.com/9gieJsH. This is my run/debug settings for app.py: https://imgur.com/6QVMebK

Comment: @sraw is referring to a toolbar icon that you can reach also under "Run - Edit configurations ...".

Comment: There is no way here to disable Flask app or disable `-m flask run` : PyCharm somehow implicitly do this. And this is bad.