# AssertionError: The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current application

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting an error when entering data from form.
`The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current application.  Please make sure to call init_app() first.`

I have initialized `init_app()` within my app.py file as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    db.init_app(app)
```

This is where I have created database URI:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///report.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

app.config.from_object(config.DevelopementConfig)
```

I have tried initialising before using app.run() but ultimately removed it as I realised I was initialising app twice.

I have not created `_init.py_` file. Is it required to create `init.py`?

I am also getting warning as SQL_ALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI not set although I am setting it up. I am also using 4 different database models.

Comment: You have to move db.init_app() out of main block as described [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764073/sqlalchemy-extension-isnt-registered-when-running-app-with-gunicorn).

Comment: I think you just need to change the order of the two lines in the main block. Init the db object first and then create the tables.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was I named a variable and then initialized that from there. I probably don't know what I'm talking about but it worked for me. Put this into the beginning of your code.

```
sqlalchemy = SQLAlchemy()
sqlalchemy.init_app(app)
```

No issues after.